# Rank query using row_number reversed

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce, window-functions

I have a query where I am ranking the returned rows ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732309/generating-a-ordered-sequence-rank-on-complex-query)). What I would like to be able to do is reverse the rank, and set the new_rank accordingly. Lets assume I have `999` entries.

For instance if I have this query:

```
with persondata as (
   SELECT firstname,
          lastname,
          year,
          personid,
        ((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(thevalue),0)
          FROM assets
          WHERE personidref = w.personid AND year = w.year)
       - (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0)
          FROM liabilities
          WHERE personidref = w.personid AND year = w.year)) as worth,
          row_number() over(ORDER BY w.worth DESC) as new_rank,
         visible
   FROM members w 
   WHERE year = 2014 
   AND visible = 1 
   ORDER BY worth ASC LIMIT 5
) 
select row_number() over (order by worth DESC) as rank,
       * 
from persondata
```

This rightly returns the bottom 5 in the desired order see below:

```
 rank | firstname |     lastname      |  worth   | new_rank
------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------
    1 | Peter     | Griffin           |  -520000 |      145 
    2 | Steve     | Moffat            |  -530000 |      519 
    3 | Gregory   | Peck              |  -540000 |      131 
    4 | Ruben     | Mumbles           |  -550000 |      130 
    5 | Ricky     | Swiss             |  -560000 |      120
```

Is there a way to incorporate the `row_count` and subtract current row count? Or set a counter to be used temporarily, that is set to row count then decrement?

Final desired result:

```
 rank | firstname |     lastname      |  worth   | new_rank 
------+-----------+-------------------+----------+----------
  997 | Peter     | Griffin           |  -520000 |      145 
  996 | Steve     | Moffat            |  -530000 |      519 
  997 | Gregory   | Peck              |  -540000 |      131 
  998 | Ruben     | Mumbles           |  -550000 |      130 
  999 | Ricky     | Swiss             |  -560000 |      120
```

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this implementation on using `row_number`.

Comment: try `count(*) over () - row_number() over(ORDER BY w.worth DESC) as new_rank`

Comment: ah yes, but if the query is `LIMIT 5` it counts the rank down as 4,3,2,1,0. As opposed to (*) being the full number of queries 999 resulting in 999,998, etc.

Comment: you can move the `count(*) over ()` into the cte to get the full count.

Comment: cte? What does this mean?

Comment: the `with` part: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Answer (score 2):

#### Problems

No wonder you got stuck with this query. Your formatting and naming conventions are **means of obfuscation** (format has been edited by now).

- It is **very confusing** that you compute `new_rank` based on `members.worth`, then compute a new `worth` (re-using the same name!) and a `rank` based on that.

  - Don't reuse the same name "worth". Use separate, meaningful identifiers.
  - Why would you call the rank based on the *old* value "new_rank"?
- Why would you compute a "rank" with `row_number()` instead of [`rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to begin with?
- Why would you use an alias `w` for a table `members`?
- Your `ORDER BY worth` uses the newly computed `worth`, not `members.worth`. Are you aware of that? It is *very unwise* to build traps like that, unless you actually *want* to obfuscate your code.
- If you want both rankings, you cannot `LIMIT 5` in the [CTE (Common Table Expression)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html). To get the relative standing, you have to compute the new `worth` for *all* relevant rows. However, it's unclear which rows are actually **relevant** for your ranking. All rows in `members`? Just the ones passing your `WHERE` conditions?
- Finally, it is undefined how to break ties. What do you expect as result if the 3rd to the 7th highest calculated `worth` are identical?

#### Solution

Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [How will the order of operations in this query affect my results?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54477/how-will-the-order-of-operations-in-this-query-affect-my-results/54565#54565)

I wouldn't use CTEs at all here. It's not needed and probably slower than a subqueries. Aggregate the sum of assets and liabilities per person *before* joining. this way, you avoid multiplying rows:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

I use `calc_worth` and `calc_rank` instead of your output columns `worth` and `rank` to untangle the naming a bit.

```
SELECT count(*) OVER ()     -- AS total_ct
       + 1                  -- counter off-by-1 error
       - rank() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(a.asset_sum, 0)
                             - COALESCE(l.liab_sum, 0)) AS calc_rank
     , m.firstname, m.lastname
     , COALESCE(a.asset_sum, 0) - COALESCE(l.liab_sum, 0) AS calc_worth
     , rank() OVER (ORDER BY m.worth DESC) AS rank
FROM  members m
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT personidref, sum(thevalue) AS asset_sum
   FROM   assets
   WHERE  year = 2014
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a ON a.personidref = m.personid
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT personidref, sum(amount) AS liab_sum
   FROM   liabilities
   WHERE  year = 2014
   ) l ON l.personidref = m.personid
WHERE  m.year = 2014 
AND    m.visible = 1 
ORDER  BY calc_worth DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

If you want to reverse the sort order in the result, wrap this in a subquery and order once more in the outer query.